# Java Spring Async performance

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, performance

We have a service that writes some data to a file. New file per request. For example:

```
GET http://service.somecompany.com/save/{data}
```

This request will create new file `/var/files/{random-name}.txt`.

Service is built with @Async to avoid clients to wait while file is writing. Please, see code examples:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save/{data}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String add(@PathVariable("data") String data) {
        someService.saveData(data);
        return "Ok!";
    }
}
```

SomeService implementation:

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {

    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> saveData(String data) {
        // file saving with BufferedWriter ...
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(successful);
    }
}
```

Currently each request will create new thread. But if I will send 100 000 requests for data saving  - they will create the maximum available number of threads. That will be writing data too slowly.
Maybe better to limit threads number:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="250" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="60" />
</bean>
```

But if to limit - which size to choose? Or maybe it is real to somehow differently increase performance? What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk IO is faster when done sequentially (especially on non-SSD drives, I think that's the case too with SSD). If your task doesn't do anything other than write to the disk (no computation which would benefit from multi-threading), I'd use only one thread.

Comment: Thanks for answer. (This is copy of comment under kaqqao's answer). Motive of using threads isn't in carrying out some calculations. Motive is in avoiding customers to wait. And it is critical. Also expected load is 100-200 requests per second. The size of data at average 1 KB. SSD will hardly be.. Therefore, anything other than the number of threads not remains..

Comment: Whether your pool have 1 thread or 200, the user won't wait, since you're invoking an asynchronous method. The job will be put in a queue, waiting for a thread to execute it. The time taken to write the 200 files will probably be wmaller with one thread than with 100, because you won't have as much context switching, and because writes will be sequential rather than concurrent. I don't understand your last two sentences.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. And thank you for a help. I will try with one thread in poll.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1. delayed write by 1 thread with prestoring persisting data
2. using async file IO like AsynchronousFileChannel (look at java 7 file capabilities or google related util libs), so you wouldn't need @Async annotation and additional thread pool

Answer (score -1):

Let's be realistic. Are you *really* going to have 100 000 simultaneous requests? Even if you see 10 000 visits a day, it's highly unlikely you'd have more than 30 at the same time, let alone for that exact URL. Plus, unless you have some ridiculously efficient SSD array, your limiting factor will be disk I/O and not the thread pool anyway. So, in conclusion, that pool should probably be rather small, maybe 10 threads, depending on the number of visitors, size of the files and disk performance, unless you really have some beastly hardware and a very high possibility of many concurrent requests.

EDIT:
I totally agree withJB Nizet. If you have a single disk, and threads do nothing but writing (no business logic), one thread is all that makes sense, as the drive can only really write one thing at a time.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Motive of using threads isn't in carrying out some calculations. Motive is in avoiding customers to wait. And it is critical. Also expected load is 100-200 requests per second. The size of data at average 1 KB. SSD will hardly be.. Therefore, anything other than the number of threads not remains..